# Efficient way to either create a list, or append to it if one already exists?

Tags: python, list

I'm going through a whole bunch of tuples with a many-to-many correlation, and I want to make a dictionary where each b of (a,b) has a list of all the a's that correspond to a b.  It seems awkward to test for a list at key b in the dictionary, then look for an a, then append a if it's not already there, every single time through the tuple digesting loop; but I haven't found a better way yet.  Does one exist? Is there some other way to do this that's a lot prettier?

Comment: by prettier you mean syntactically or algorithmically?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for the `setdefault()` method:

> setdefault(key[, default])
>   If key is
>   in the dictionary, return its value.
>   If not, insert key with a value of
>   default and return default. default
>   defaults to None.

You can use this as a single call that will get b if it exists, or set b to an empty list if it doesn't already exist - and either way, return b:

```
>>> key = 'b'
>>> val = 'a'
>>> print d
{}
>>> d.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
>>> print d
{'b': ['a']}
>>> d.setdefault(key, []).append('zee')
>>> print d
{'b': ['a', 'zee']}
```

Combine this with a simple "not in" check and you've done what you're after in three lines:

```
>>> b = d.setdefault('b', [])
>>> if val not in b:
...   b.append(val)
... 
>>> print d
{'b': ['a', 'zee', 'c']}
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is a bit nicer than `setdefault`, assuming you have Python 2.5 or higher.

Comment: I'm stuck with 2.34, so this is actually the answer, for me--thanks, James!

Comment: D'oh.  `set()` is nice but isn't built in until 2.4.  Why's your Python so old?  :-(

Comment: `defaultdict` also requires an additional import of `collections`

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you're not really tied to lists, [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) are quite handy.

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(set)
for a, b in mappings:
    d[b].add(a)
```

If you *really* want lists instead of sets, you could follow this with a

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    d[k] = list(v)
```

And if you *really* want a dict instead of a defaultdict, you can say

```
d = dict(d)
```

I don't really see any reason you'd want to, though.

Comment: ah yes, this gets around the initial check for no value.  Thanks! I learned something new. :)

Comment: +1 for `defaultdict`, because it really is the most Pythonic solution.

Comment: I also liked how [this guy helped me come up with defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))](http://ohuiginn.net/mt/2010/07/nested_dictionaries_in_python.html)

Comment: If you want list instead of set, you can do this:
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for a, b in mappings:
    d[b].append(a)

Answer (score 5):

Use collections.defaultdict

```
your_dict = defaultdict(list)
for (a,b) in your_list:
    your_dict[b].append(a)
```

Comment: OP's "then append a if it's not already there" makes me think that the original list may have duplicates that should be filtered out, which is why I used `set` instead of `list`.

Comment: @ephemient: ahhh, the unbound it.  If "it" means simply the list, then `defaultict(list)` is right.  If "it" means each item within the set, then `defaultdict(set)` is right.  And when "it" rains, what is "it" bound to then?

Comment: It would have been nice if OP had their (presumably) working, ugly code instead of an ambiguous description in English :-)

Comment: @ephemient: That's why I voted your answer up... I think it might be better because `set` might make more sense than a `list`.

Answer (score 4):

you can sort your tuples O(n log n) then create your dictionary O(n)

or simplier O(n) but could impose heavy load on memory in case of many tuples:

```
your_dict = {}
for (a,b) in your_list:
    if b in your_dict:
        your_dict[b].append(a)
    else:
        your_dict[b]=[a]
```

Hmm it's pretty much the same as you've described. What's awkward about that?

You could also consider using an sql database to do the dirty work.

Comment: The simpler method is O(n), by the way, so it's preferable to the sort your tuples method.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an `if`, AFAIK it is more *pythonic* to use a `try` block instead.

```
your_list=[('a',1),('a',3),('b',1),('f',1),('a',2),('z',1)]

your_dict={}
for (a,b) in your_list:
    try:
        your_dict[b].append(a)
    except KeyError:
        your_dict[b]=[a]

print your_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you will get out of the key test, but once they key/value pair has been initialized it is easy :)

```
d = {}
if 'b' not in d:
  d['b'] = set()
d['b'].add('a')
```

The set will ensure that only 1 of 'a' is in the collection.  You need to do the initial 'b' check though to make sure the key/value exist.

Comment: curious why -1?  is this wrong somehow?  I will delete the answer if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Dict `get` method?
It returns the value of `my_dict[some_key]` if `some_key` is in the dictionary, and if not - returns some default value (`[]` in the example below):

```py
my_dict[some_key] = my_dict.get(some_key, []).append(something_else)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `append` doesn't return the list. It becomes `my_dict[some_key] = None`.

Comment: Fix is: `my_dict[some_key] = my_dict.get(some_key, []) + [something_else]`

Answer (score 0):

There's another way that's rather efficient (though maybe not as efficient as sets) and simple. It's similar in practice to `defaultdict` but does not require an additional import.
Granted that you have a dict with empty (None) keys, it means you also create the dict keys somewhere. You can do so with the `dict.fromkeys` method, and this method also allows for setting a default value to all keys.

```
keylist = ['key1', 'key2']
result = dict.fromkeys(keylist, [])
```

where `result` will be:
    {'key1': [], 'key2': []}

Then you can do your loop and use `result['key1'].append(..)` directly