# how to invert another function in a dictionary and how to count the inverted value if its not unique in the report?

Tags: python

my load library is working well but the other too failed..
how to invert another function in a dictionary(index by author) and how to count the inverted value if its not unique in the report(report author count)?

```
       def load_library(f):    
            with open(f,'rt') as x:
                return dict(map(str.strip, line.split("|")) for line in x)

        def index_by_author(f):    
            return {value:key for key, value in load_library(f).items()}

def count_authors(file_name):
     invert = {}
     for k, v in load_library(file_name).items():
        invert[v] = invert.get(v, 0) + 1
     return invert
def write_authors_counts(counts, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fobj:
        for name, count in counts.items():
            fobj.write('{}: {}\n'.format(name, count))

def report_author_counts(lib_fpath, rep_filepath):
    counts = count_authors(lib_fpath)
    write_authors_counts(counts, rep_filepath)
```

Load library

```
In module library.py, implement function load_library().

Inputs:
Path to a text file (with contents similar to those above) containing the individual books.
Outputs:
The function shall produce a dictionary where the book titles are used as keys and the authors' names are stored as values.
You can expect that the input text file will always exist, but it may be empty. In that case, the function shall return an empty dictionary.

It can then be used as follows:

>>> from library import load_library
>>> book_author = load_library('books.txt')
>>> print(book_author['RUR'])
Capek, Karel
>>> print(book_author['Dune'])
Herbert, Frank
```

Index by author

```
In module library.py, create function index_by_author(), which - in a sense - inverts the dictionary of books produced by load_library().

Inputs:
A dictionary with book titles as keys and book authors as values (the same structure as produced by load_library() function).
Outputs:
A dictionary containing book authors as keys and a list of all books of the respective author as values.
If the input dictionary is empty, the function shall produce an empty dictionary as well.

For example, running the function on the following book dictionary (with reduced contents for the sake of brevity) would produce results shown below in the code:

>>> book_author = {'RUR': 'Capek, Karel', 'Dune': 'Herbert, Frank', 'Children of Dune': 'Herbert, Frank'}
>>> books_by = index_by_author(book_author)
>>> print(books_by)
{'Herbert, Frank': ['Dune', 'Children of Dune'], 'Capek, Karel': ['RUR']}
>>> books_by['Capek, Karel']
['RUR']
>>> books_by['Herbert, Frank']
['Dune', 'Children of Dune']
```

Report author counts

```
    In module library.py, create function report_author_counts(lib_fpath, rep_filepath) which shall compute the number of books of each author and the total number of books, and shall store this information in another text file.

    Inputs:
    Path to a library text file (containing records for individual books).
    Path to report text file that shall be created by this function.
    Outputs: None
    Assuming the file books.txt has the same contents as above, running the function like this:

    >>> report_author_counts('books.txt', 'report.txt')
    shall create a new text file report.txt with the following contents:

    Clarke, Arthur C.: 2
    Herbert, Frank: 2
    Capek, Karel: 1
    Asimov, Isaac: 3
    TOTAL BOOKS: 8
    The order of the lines is irrelevant. Do not forget the TOTAL BOOKS line! If the input file is empty, the output file shall contain just the line TOTAL BOOKS: 0.

    Suggestion: There are basically 2 ways how to implement this function. You can either

    use the 2 above functions to load the library, transform it using index_by_author() and then easilly iterate over the dictionary, or
    you can work directly with the source text file, extract the author names, and count their occurences.
    Both options are possible, provided the function will accept the specified arguments and will produce the right file contents. The choice is up to you.
```

python

Comment: please don't vandalize this question; that wasted the effort people spent answering it.  I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index_by_author` function needs to be a little more complex than the dict comprehension you suggested.  `dict.setdefault()` comes in handy here, as described in [Efficient way to either create a list, or append to it if one already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052111/efficient-way-to-either-create-a-list-or-append-to-it-if-one-already-exists).  Notice too that your assignment says a dictionary should be the parameter, not a file.  Here is what I recommend:

```
def index_by_author(book_author):
    dict_by_author = {}
    for key, value in book_author.items():
        dict_by_author.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
    return dict_by_author
```

Then in your `report_author_counts()`, you can use `index_by_author()` to invert the dictionary.  Then loop through the inverted dictionary.  For each item, the count will be the length of the value, which will be a list of titles.  The length of a list is determined with `len(list)`.

Comment: thanks it worked well and i have tried to make report_author by making three more functions in to it but it didn''t work i updated my code ....i dont understand how to make the lenght of the count? @jim-k

Comment: Change the line `invert[v] = invert.get(v, 0) + 1` to use `k`'s instead of `v`'s and I think it will work.  If you have further problems then please show error messages or incorrect output in your question.